# Can't resolve (Firebase)User expression expected

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

Just trying to make a phone authentication as per a tutorial i'm watching which I have written down the code as below, but i keep getting the error expression expected for 'User' - I am completely new to this so I imagine it's something simple I need help nonetheless! Thank you in advance!

```
mCallbacks = new PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {
    @Override
    public void onVerificationCompleted(@NonNull PhoneAuthCredential phoneAuthCredential) {
        signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(phoneAuthCredential);


    }

    private void signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(PhoneAuthCredential phoneAuthCredential) {
        FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signInWithCredential(phoneAuthCredential).addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<Credential.UserCredential>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Credential.UserCredential> task) {
                if(task.isSuccessful())
                    userIsLoggedIn();

            }

            private void userIsLoggedIn() {
                User = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
                if(User != null){
                    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainPageActivity.class));
                    finish();
                    return;
```

Comment: Variable `User` had never been defined.

Comment: How is the `User` object defined? Please respond with @AlexMamo

Answer (score 0):

You have a class named `"User"` and you didn't define its variable here which showing java expression error . Actually you are looking for User of Firebase , FirebaseAuth has class `FirebaseUser` . So it should be below code to check current user .

```
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
                if(user != null){.....
```

**Update (cause of new error)** - You are implementing `PhoneAuthCredential` , but passing Username-password based `Credential.UserCredential`  and implemeting wrong method.

Your `signInWithPhoneAuthCredential` void would be -

```
private void signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(PhoneAuthCredential phoneAuthCredential) {
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signInWithCredential(phoneAuthCredential).addOnCompleteListener(this , new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            userIsLoggedIn();
        } else {
            //
        }
    }
});
}
```

And your attached code would be -

```
  mCallbacks = new PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {
        @Override
        public void onVerificationCompleted(@NonNull PhoneAuthCredential phoneAuthCredential) {
            signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(phoneAuthCredential);
        }

        @Override
        public void onVerificationFailed(@NonNull FirebaseException e) {
            //TODO
        }

        @Override
        public void onCodeSent(@NonNull String s, @NonNull PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken forceResendingToken) {
            super.onCodeSent(s, forceResendingToken);

            //TODO

        }
    };
}


private void signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(PhoneAuthCredential phoneAuthCredential) {
    FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signInWithCredential(phoneAuthCredential).addOnCompleteListener(this , new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                userIsLoggedIn();
            } else {
                //
            }
        }
    });
}

private void userIsLoggedIn() {
    FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    if (user != null) {
        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainPageActivity.class));
        finish();
        //  return;
    }
}
```

Please check the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/phone-auth).

Comment: if i do that i get the error: Cannot resolve method 'addOnCompleteListener(anonymous com.google.firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks, anonymous com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener<android.net.wifi.hotspot2.pps.Credential.UserCredential>)'